# Adding column in sqoop import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

While importing data from SQL through sqoop, Is it possible to add a new column and insert time stamp into that column?

Is it possible by any other ways before getting data into HDFS?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please show what you have already tried. Your question, as it currently is will probably not receive a good answer, and may be closed. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site. Good luck!

Comment: After you finish the database transfer, it should be easily possible to add a new column to the new database, the way you normally would. Or, you could add the new column in the existing database before performing the transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use --query parameter of sqoop command and add SQL function to get current timestamp in query.

Example: To import stud table from MySQL having rollnum and name columns.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username root --query 'select name, rollnum, current_timestamp from stud where $CONDITIONS' --target-dir '/tmp/stud1' --split-by id
```

Note current_timestamp mysql function used in query.